# Excel VB not starting

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently installed Excel 2016. I'm unable to access the VB editor, when I try to open it from the developer tab it comes up blank.

[image]

Any ideas? I've never come across this before and can't see anything online.

Comment: I've faced this once and I simply restarted Excel to get everything in order.

Comment: It looks fine to me. You'll need to tell it what module you want to work on.  By default, it will only have the workbook module and a sheet module for each worksheet.  You can doubleclick on one of those and it will bring up that module's code window.  Alternately, you could insert a new module (often called a standard module) and it will show the code window for that.

Comment: You could try pressing Ctrl+r to bring up the project explorer

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have tried restarting excel; updating; uninstalling and re-installing; I have also tried repairing. However I cannot get the menu bar and toolbar to show in VB editor in any office programme. I have Office 2016 and run Windows 10.

Comment: Run excel in safe mode (disable add-ons) and see if the issue persists. ?